# Add method to dynamically created class that calls 'super'

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass

I need to create a dynamically generated class that contains a method that calls its parent's method.

The usual method to dynamically create a class is the following:

```
# I have a class ClassA...
class ClassA(object):
  def print_something(self):
    print('I am a method defined in ClassA')

# ... and I want to create a dynamically created class that inherits from ClassA
def class_s_factory(print_str):
  def print_something(self):
    print('I am a method defined in ClassS')
    print(print_str)
  cls = type('ClassS', (ClassA, ), {'print_something': print_something})
  return cls

# I can finally create an instance of ClassS and use the 'print_something' method

# Get a string from the database (for example)
print_str_database = 'I am a string from the database'

test_class = class_s_factory(print_str_database)
test_instance = test_class()
test_instance.print_something()

# This will print
# I am a method defined in ClassS
# I am a string from the database
```

What if I wanted to call the parent's method in `print_something`?
How can I change it? For example:

```
def print_something(self):
  # CALL PARENT'S METHOD HERE! HOW?
  print('I am a method defined in ClassS')
  print(print_str)
```

I want the following output

```
# I am a method defined in ClassA
# I am a method defined in ClassS
# I am a string from the database
```

I tried something I propose as an answer. It works, but are there any better ways to deal with the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up trying, and it works:

```
class ClassA(object):
  def print_something(self):
    print('I am a method defined in ClassA')

# Create a factory for classes.
# Each class has a method that depends on the string given
# This method needs to call its parent's method
def class_s_factory(print_str):
  def add_print_something(cls):
     def print_something(self):
       super(cls, self).print_something()
       print('I am a method defined in ClassS')
       print(print_str)
     setattr(cls, 'print_something', print_something)

  cls = type('ClassS', (ClassA, ), {})
  add_print_something(cls)
  return cls

# Get a string from the database (for example)
print_str_database = 'I am a string from the database'

test_class = class_s_factory(print_str_database)
test_instance = test_class()
test_instance.print_something()
```

However, in principle there could exist better ways of obtaining the same result.

Comment: I think people were a little confused by the phrasing of your answer, since we see a lot of people using answers for things that are continuations of the question. I've tweaked the wording to make it clearer that this is indeed an answer to your question.